# "Edit contact" screen is not removed from "recents" tab after editing

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am trying to call the "Edit contact" screen from my application using the following code:

```
Intent editIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
editIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
editIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
editIntent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE, editPhoneNumber);
editIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(editIntent);
```

After editing, it returns to my application. But while checking the "recents" tab the "contact" applications screen is still existing and on clicking that, it again prompts me to save the phone number given previously.

Please help here. How to finish the "edit contact" activity completely.

Comment: does adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` flag help?

Comment: Ya.. Thanks very much Hughzi.... I have been very silly :)

Comment: No problem, ill put as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS` to your intent and it will have the behavior you desire.